# Sql string adding problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
SELECT a.one + ' test ' +b.two from table1 a right join table1 on a.id =b.id
```

The problem is that when one is null then it the whole string is null, is there some kind of trick to bypass this problem
msSQL 2005

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2811733/concatenating-results-from-sql-query-and-null-columns/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for the [`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) function:

```
SELECT ISNULL(a.one,'') + ' test ' + ISNULL(b.two , '')
from table1 a 
right join table1 b 
  on a.id =b.id
```

If the first argument of the `ISNULL` function is null, then the second argument is supplied.
This way, none of the concatenated fields will return a null and you will get a string and not a null.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want the outcome to be when one or both inputs is null. If you just want each part to collapse to an empty string, use ISNULL:

```
ISNULL(a.one, '') + ' test ' + ISNULL(b.two, '')
```

Otherwise, you'll have to get clever with a CASE expression.

Answer (score 1):

There are several variations depending on what output you want

```
-- leading/trailing spaces on test
SELECT ISNULL(a.one,'') + ' test ' + ISNULL(b.two , '')

-- no spacing around test
SELECT ISNULL(a.one,' ') + 'test' + ISNULL(' ' + b.two, '')

-- do you want the word test at all if one is blank?
SELECT ISNULL(a.one + ' test','') + ISNULL(' ' + b.two, '')
```